# Interacting with Tkinter window during a long process

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a basic python class that creates a window using the standard `Tkinter` library:

```
import Tkinter

class GUI(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def lock_func(self):
        while 1==1:
            print "blah"

    def initialize(self):
        self.processBtn = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Process", command=self.lock_func)
        self.processBtn.pack()        

app = GUI(None)
app.mainloop()
```

when I hit the `Process` button, the window doesn't respond.
I want to be able to close the program (using the x button) whene the `lock_func` is runing.

Comment: What you're describing isn't directly possible. `Tkinter` is single threaded. You'll need to use the `multiprocessing` module or `threading` module to make  this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [generator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) to hold the state within the loop, and use `yield` to relinquish control back to the main loop. Then use [self.after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to repeatedly call the generator's `next` method to simulate the effect of `while True` -- but doing it in a way which is friendly to Tkinter's main loop.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.initialize()

    def lock_func(self):
        def step():
            while True:
                print("blah")
                self.nextstep_id = self.master.after(1, nextstep)
                yield
        nextstep = step().next
        self.nextstep_id = self.master.after(1, nextstep)

    def stop(self):
        self.master.after_cancel(self.nextstep_id)
        print("stopped")

    def initialize(self):
        self.nextstep_id = 0
        self.process_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Process",
                                        command=self.lock_func)
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Stop",
                                     command=self.stop)        
        self.process_button.pack()
        self.stop_button.pack(expand='yes', fill='x')

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would suggest using some other variable name than `update`, since it can easily be confused with the widget method `update()` -- I almost made that mistake when replying, until I took a second look and realized `update` was a temporary variable rather than a function call.

Comment: Don't forget to change both places where you call update/nextstep (ie: inside the while loop)

Comment: Making 100 miliseconds pause in each iteration, makes the loop considerably slow, I want it to be as fastest as possible

Comment: I'm sure you know how to fix that :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `window.update()` method too keep your GUI active and functional after every time you change something on it. During the roots `mainloop`, this happens automatically but if you're prolonging the mainloop it's probably a good idea to do it manually your self. Put the `window.update()` in the loop that is taking a while. *Note: `window` is a `Tk()` object*

Comment: `window.update()` doesn't just update the window, it also processes any pending events of any type - typing, button clicks, scrolling, etc. If you want to only update the display you should call `window.update_idletasks()`. You should also warn that calling `update` is a little dangerous, in that if an event occurs that causes this same function to be called again, you'll end up with nested eventloops.

Comment: I assumed that OP wanted his GUI to still be functional while the processing occurs.

Comment: Right, I understand. Calling `update` is a good quick fix for an example program, though there are often better ways to structure a real program. It's just that your answer is a little misleading to say that `update` "updates the windown" when it actually does a lot more.

Comment: I've been using the `update` method. I never really considered what you said in your first comment, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use threading:

```
import Tkinter
import thread

class GUI(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def lock_func(self):
        while 1==1:
            print "blah"

    def initialize(self):
        self.processBtn = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Process", command=lambda: thread.start_new_thread(self.lock_func, ()))
        self.processBtn.pack()        

app = GUI(None)
app.mainloop()
```

However, it will keep printing until you close the Python console.

To stop it, you can use another button that changes a variable:

```
import Tkinter
import thread

class GUI(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.shouldPrint = True
        self.initialize()

    def lock_func(self):
        while self.shouldPrint:
            print "blah"

    def setShouldPrint(self, value):
        self.shouldPrint = value

    def initialize(self):
        self.processBtn = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Process", command=lambda: thread.start_new_thread(self.lock_func, ()))
        self.stopBtn = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Stop", command = lambda: self.setShouldPrint(False))
        self.processBtn.grid(row = 1)
        self.stopBtn.grid(row = 2)


app = GUI(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: No way to stop it with another button ?